# How to end recursion when following a set of links for web scraping using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

My aim is to extract from as many articles as I can on a news website by following the links. However, after running this code, it doesn't seem like it will ever end unless I force stop it. Is there a good strategy to end this recursion when following links on a website? I also start on a specific article's page rather than the home page of the site.

Secondly, what does Scrapy's response.urljoin do exactly? Any kind of example would be appreciated!

```
    class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "spidy"
        allowed_domains = ["www.news.com"]
        def start_requests(self):
            urls = [
                'https://www.news.com/news/asia-243',
            ]
            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

        def parse(self, response):
            for elem in response.css('a::attr(href)').getall():
                if re.search(r'\/news\/[a-zA-Z-]+\d{3}', elem):
                    new_url = response.urljoin(elem)
                    yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse)

            yield {
                'title': response.css('h1::text').get(),
                'full_date' :  response.xpath('//div/time').get(),
                'time_seconds' : response.xpath('//div/seconds').get(),
                'content': response.css('div.inner p::text').getall(),
                'labels': response.css('#topic-tag a::text').getall()
            }
```

Comment: You shouldn’t not have a problem of _recursion_, because Scrapy ignores duplicate requests by default.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy has a [`CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-pagecount) setting to close the spider after visiting a certain number of pages. You can set this in the [normal ways](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings) e.g.

```
scrapy run spider newsspider.py -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=10
```

`response.urljoin` just wraps the [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) function (for python 3!) in the standard library passing `response.url` as the first argument e.g.

```
response.urljoin('xyz')
```

is equivalent to

```
urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, 'xyz')
```

Answer (score 1):

> urljoin(url)

Constructs an **absolute url** by combining the Response’s url with a possible relative url.

```
scrapy shell https://realpython.com/
In [2]: response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
Out[2]:
['/',
 '/start-here/',
 '#',
 '/',
 '/courses/',
 '/quizzes/',
 '/learning-paths/',
 '/tutorials/all/',
 '/account/join/',
 '#',
 '/account/join/',
 '/products/python-basics-book/',
 '/products/python-tricks-book/',
 '/products/real-python-course/',
 '/products/managing-python-dependencies/',
 '/products/sublime-python/',
 '/products/pythonic-wallpapers/',

In [5]: asdf = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()

In [6]: for aqqq in asdf:
    ...:     print(response.urljoin(str(aqqq)))
    ...:
    ...:
https://realpython.com/
https://realpython.com/start-here/
https://realpython.com/
https://realpython.com/
https://realpython.com/courses/
https://realpython.com/quizzes/
https://realpython.com/learning-paths/
https://realpython.com/tutorials/all/
https://realpython.com/account/join/
https://realpython.com/
https://realpython.com/account/join/
https://realpython.com/products/python-basics-book/
```